# Write PHP associative array inside for with generated values? It messes all up

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

For some reason this:

```
        $retVal = array();
        $numberedWrapper = array();

        for ($i=0; $i<$amount; $i++)
        {
            while (!$this->checkUsername($username, $retVal, $services))
            {
                // Crea un nuevo número usando un random entre uno y mil
                $randomNumber = rand (1, 1000);

                // Concatenar la raíz del username
                $username = $usernameRoot . $randomNumber;
            }
            array_push($retVal, $username);
        }

        return $retVal;
```

Generates this:

```
{
  "result": [
    "Will160",
    "Will913",
    "Will647"
  ]
}
```

But if I just change this line:

```
array_push($retVal, $username);
```

to this:

```
array_push($retVal, array($i => $username));
```

to create an associative array, the result returned is this:

```
{
  "result": [
    [
      "Will559"
    ],
    {
      "1": "Will559"
    },
    {
      "2": "Will559"
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see only by adding content to an associative array, it seems to override the first two values for `$username` with the last one, strangely this doesn't happen with the key value (`$i`). Also, when passing the value into a unidimensional array as in the first example, everything works perfectly.

I am sure I am missing something here, I have been working with PHP for a few months now, I am a C# developer. Probably for a PHP expert this will be very obvious. Can please somebody share any ideas on why is this happening? I am trying to generate (at the end) something like this:

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "suggested": "Will525"
    },
    {
      "suggested": "Will249"
    },
    {
      "suggested": "Will870"
    }
  ]
}
```

I will be glad to vote the answer that correct this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try: `$retVal[] = ["suggested" => $username];` instead of: `array_push($retVal, $username);`

Comment: I just did right now, and it doesn't work :(, same thing: {
  "result": [
    {
      "suggested": "WillDeLaVega41"
    },
    {
      "suggested": "WillDeLaVega41"
    },
    {
      "suggested": "WillDeLaVega41"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: ^ Isn't that exactly what you wanted ?

Comment: look the number generated, it is always 41, it should generate different random numbers for each "suggested" object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    $retVal = array();
    $numberedWrapper = array();

    for ($i=0; $i<$amount; $i++)
    {
        while (!$this->checkUsername($username, $retVal, $services))
        {
            // Crea un nuevo número usando un random entre uno y mil
            $randomNumber = rand (1, 1000);

            // Concatenar la raíz del username
            $username = $usernameRoot . $randomNumber;
            **array_push($retVal, $username);**
        }            
    }

    return $retVal;
```

And I really can't see why you have a while. It seems like you need an simple if here...

Comment: The reason for the while is because a little before I receive the $amount variable which is the number of available usernames to return, then the while loop verifies if the user is available (not dup in the database and in the array itself), then if the result is ok, it should add it to the returned array.

Comment: The reason this won't work is that it will return an unidimensional array, what I need here is to return an array of objects that will be received by an angular js app in the client and then will feed an ng-repeat. Also the instruction should be outside the while since being outside means that the suggested username is not in the database (that's what $this->checkUsername does). (btw, this is an apigility web service).

Comment: Oh I see now. Have you tried this? array_push($retVal, array($username)); so you don't specify the index.

Comment: yes, at this time the only way I could solve the issue was to first recover an unidimensional array and then pass it to a function where I used it to create a new object. That worked, however I really would like to get an expert opinion on why this code doesn't work. In C# or any other language that I know I think this should work... or maybe I am missing something.